# defining a function in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

the moment you guess the correct number, it freezes and doesn't proceed further, however if I don't define the function *do_guess_round* and instead simply write the code after the second *while True* statement it works perfectly. I guess I am incorrectly defining the function

```
import random
computers_number = random.randint(1,100)
prompt=('what is your guess? ')

def do_guess_round():
    """choose a random number, prompt the user to guess it
    check whether the user is true, 
    and repeat the pocess untill the user is correct"""
while True:
    players_guess=input (prompt)
    if computers_number == int(players_guess):
      print ('correct! well done')
      break
    elif computers_number<int(players_guess):
      print ("incorrect, your guess is higher")
    else:
      print ('incorrect, your guess is lower')

print ("Starting a new round ")
print ("let the guessing game begin")      

while True:
    do_guess_round()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking about. What is the code you've shown doing incorrectly? What do you expect it to do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Current your `do_guess_round()` function does not do anything. You need to indent the code that is supposed to be contained in it. The `while True` beneath it is not indented, so the body of the function currently only consists of the string:

```
"""choose a random number, prompt the user to guess it
check whether the user is true, 
and repeat the pocess untill the user is correct"""
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you guess the correct number, your code collapses to

```
def do_guess_round():
    while True:
          break

while True:
    do_guess_round()
```

No surprise it freezes, you haven't built any way for it to quit - `break` only leaves one level of loop. Presumably you're going to move the code to generate numbers into the function? You need something more like

```
def do_guess_round():
    # read player guess here

    if guess matches:
          return True
    else: 
          return False

result = False
while result != True:
    result = do_guess_round()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def do_guess_round():
    """choose a random number, prompt the user to guess it
    check whether the user is true, 
    and repeat the pocess untill the user is correct"""
while True:
```

The "while True" loop isn't indented, so it isn't in the function, indent the loop an it's contents, then you should be fine.